# I need to choose a collection

Tags: java, collections

Here is my specific assignment:

> I must implement Address, Customer, Product.
>
> In the EComDB class, functions to search / remove Customer or
>   Product. You will need to choose a collection to hold these Customers
>   and Products.

I am searching for any good tips/suggestions or tutorials on how to start down this road.  Please keep in mind I am new to Java.

Thank you in advance for any direction.

Here is the beginning of my Product class with bare bones constructor.

```
package blah;

public class Product {
    private String sku;
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private double price;
    private long quantityOnHand;
    public Product (String sku, String name, String desc,double price, long quantityOnHand) {

    }
    public String getSku() {
        return sku;
    }
    public void setSku(String sku) {
        this.sku = sku;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public long getQuantityOnHand() {
        return quantityOnHand;
    }
    public void setQuantityOnHand(long quantityOnHand) {
        this.quantityOnHand = quantityOnHand;
    }
}
```

Here is what I have to start with on the EComDB class:

```
package blah;


public class EComDB {

    // TODO choose a collection data structure to store Customer and Product

    public Customer searchById(String id) {
        return null;
    }

    public void addCustomer(Customer c) {

    }

    public void removeCustomer(String id) {

    }

    public Product searchBySku(String sku) {
        return null;
    }

    public void addProduct(Product p) {

    }

    public void removeProduct(String sku) {

    }

}
```

Comment: It seems you want to uniquely identify a product by its sku, and a custome by its ID. And you need to find a product by its sku and a customer by its ID. Two Maps look like the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

Many are suited, but I would probably go with [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) if `Product.sku` and `Customer.id` are unique, you can use them as the Map key for fast access in your implemented find methods.

Initialize: `private Map<String, Customer> customers = new HashMap<>();`

Insert: `customers.put(yourCustomerObject.getId(), yourCustomer);`

Find: `customers.get(id);`

etc...

HashSet is also a good one for the guarantee of unique objects within, but Map is more convenient to retrieve, and since you are learning, it is a very useful collection that you should get acquainted with.

Comment: thank you for the direction.  I will see what I can do with this.